# SQL Variable not updating properly

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm having a problem with one of my variables not updating properly inside of while loop. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

```
use database
declare @sumPrice decimal(10,2) = 0.0
declare @rowPrice decimal(10,2) = 0.0
declare @numRows int = (select count(*) from Products)
declare @iterator int = 1

while @iterator <= @numRows 
begin
    set @rowPrice = (select UnitPrice from Products p
                     where p.ProductID = @iterator and UnitsInStock > 110)
    set @sumPrice += @rowPrice
    set @iterator += 1
end
Print 'The sum is ' +  convert(varchar, @sumPrice, 1)
go
```

The problem is that @sumPrice never gets updated. @iterator gets updated just fine and by the end of the while, its 77. While debugging the code, @rowPrice gets updated to the current row's price, but when it comes time to add it to @sumPrice, it never happens. @sumPrice remains blank for the entire loop and the print statement doesn't even print either. How can I fix this?

Edit: A solution was found to the problem, Turns out NULLs getting added to the variable were resulting in the variable returning NULL. Instead of straight up adding to the variable, you need to use the coalesce function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@sumprice` starts with a `NULL` value.  Adding anything to a `NULL` value returns `NULL`.

This is easy to fix.  Initialize the value before the loop:

```
set @sumprice = 0;
```

before the loop.

Or, adjust the increment to:

```
set @sumPrice = coalesce(@sumPrice, 0) + @rowPrice;
```

To be safe, you should be sure that `@rowPrice` is also not `NULL`:

```
set @sumPrice = coalesce(@sumPrice, 0) + coalesce(@rowPrice, 0);
```

If `@rowPrice` is `NULL` for even one iteration, then you will lose the value.

Comment: I tried both of those solutions. No change on the behavior or output.

Comment: @SteelSlayer . . . The original version of your question had no initialization of the variables.

Comment: Yes I edited it after Gordon replied to include the initialization, so it would not be pointed out again.

Comment: Apologies the "set @sumPrice = coalesce(@sumPrice, 0) + coalesce(@rowPrice, 0);" worked just fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because the inner query is returning null for the p.ProductID when the UnitsInStock is not greater than 110.  The NULL is summed with real values, resulting in NULL.  A workaround is to COALESCE the NULL. You also need to set the variable value, which you already fixed.

```
while @iterator <= @numRows 
begin
    set @rowPrice = (SELECT COALESCE((select UnitPrice 
                                        from Products p
                                       where p.ProductID = @iterator and UnitsInStock > 110
                                     ), 0)
                    )

    set @sumPrice += @rowPrice
set @iterator += 1
end

SELECT 'The sum is ' + CAST(@sumPrice as varchar)
```

Comment: I see it now, thanks. The null values were messing with the output.